# Why does `logistf` give error in R, while `glm` works smoothly

Tags: r, package, regression, glm, logistf

I have run `glm` (for a logistic regression) and as result I got that the algorithm diverges.
I want to try the function `logistf` to check whether Firth's approach can improve my data analysis.
Let `dat` denote my dataframe and `y ~ f1 + f2` be my model. Trying

```
fit <- logistf(y ~ f1 + f2, dat)
```

or

```
fit <- logistf(y ~ f1 + f2, data=dat)
```

I always get the error

```
Error in logistf.fit(x = x, y = y, weight = weight, offset = offset, firth,  : 
no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

As `glm` runs smoothly, I do not see how my data structure could be the source of error (this is why I have not described `dat` explicitly). Do you see any potential conflict? I thank you very much,
Avitus

Comment: I am unclear.  You wrote that with glm the algorithm diverges but you also wrote that glm runs smoothly.  Maybe post results of the glm analysis along with any associated messages.

Comment: @Mark: glm diverges: this is a result I do accept; so for me the package runs and provides me with a sound answer. The problem with logistf is that it gives no answer at all, due to the above error message. What puzzles me is that the data and the model I use in both cases are the same...

Comment: I think we need a reproducible example, please: http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000